# SVNKit keeps asking for username and password

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, subclipse

To `svn co` or `svn commit` from Terminal I do not need a username or password. However when I use Subclipse 1.8.22 with SVNKit (Pure Java) 1.7.9 on Eclipse 3.7.2, and I try to commit, a form will pop up saying "Enter Username and Password".

How do I fix this? I do not have or need a user/pass to work with this repository.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use JavaHL.  JavaHL uses the same native libraries as the command line client so it should behave the same.  More information is here:

http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL

It is unlikely you can commit to any repository without credentials.  I would guess your command line client has simply cached your credentials.